# Hex char to int conversion

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm reading data from UART byte by byte. This is saved to a char.
The byte following the start byte gives the number of subsequents bytes incoming (as a hexadecimal). I need to convert this hex number to an integer, to keep count of bytes required to be read.

Presently I'm simply type-casting to int. Here's my code:

```
char ch;
int bytes_to_read;
while(1){
    serial_read(UART_RX, &ch, sizeof(char));
    if(/*2nd byte*/){
        bytes_to_read = (int)ch;
    }
}
```

I read about strtol(), but it takes char arrays as input. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example? How is the hex number encoded in the byte?

Comment: Does "as a hexadecimal" mean it's coming as text, in hexadecimal notation? I ask because many people here seem to say "hex" when they mean "binary", i.e. as raw bytes.

Comment: which hex number you want to convert?mention it clearly

Comment: I get 0x03 when there are 3 more bytes incoming.

Comment: @user3490458: in that case your code is already doing the right thing, i.e. just casting the `char` to an `int` - so what's the actual problem ?

Comment: @user3490458 Do you get this `0x03` really as 4 characters `0`, `x`, `0` and `3` or as one byte with the *representation* `0x03` and the value 3? Be sure you are clear about the distinction of value and representation.

Comment: I get it as one byte. I was just unsure my method was the right way to go. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but assuming that `ch` is a hexadecimal character representing the number of bytes, then you could just use a simple function to convert from hex to int, e.g.

```
int hex2int(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}
```

and then:

```
bytes_to_read = hex2int(ch);
```

---

Note however that if `ch` is really just a raw value (i.e. not a hex character) then your existing method should be fine:

```
bytes_to_read = (int)ch;
```

Comment: Why not just use `atoi()`?

Comment: @codemonkey: two main reasons: (i) `atoi` works with strings, not individual `char`s and (ii) `atoi` works with decimal (base 10) numbers, not hex (base 16).

Answer (score 3):

`strtol` works on a string, `ch` is a `char`, so convert `this` char to a valid string

```
char str[2] = {0};
char chr = 'a';

str[0] = chr;
```

and use `strtol` with base `16`:

```
long num = strtol(str, NULL, 16);

printf("%ld\n", num);
```

Comment: Kinda overkill to use a whole char array when dealing with a single char.

Comment: @user3932000 What overkill?  The 2 bytes array is on the stack and there is no dynamic memory involved nor an expensive task to perform, please revise your  concept of what is an overkill.

Comment: The concept itself is overkill imo—converting a char to a length-1 string, calling a library function on it, then casting to an int... when a simple if-then function would do.

Answer (score 0):

i think easy way :

```
unsigned char x = 0xff;
    int y = (int) x; 
    printf("Hex: %X, Decimal: %d\n",x,x);
    printf("y = %d",y);
```

for more info :
https://www.includehelp.com/c/working-with-hexadecimal-values-in-c-programming-language.aspx