# Arduino CRC32C vs CRC32

Tags: arrays, c, arduino, checksum, crc32

I'm trying to write a function for my Arduino that take in a hex `char *` and returns its hex checksum. I've been able to parse and iterate through my `char *` but I haven't had the correct checksum return. Can someone help me find my bug or a better way to compute this?

So initially I tried following [this tutorial](https://excamera.com/sphinx/article-crc.html) for CRC32 and modifying it to CRC32C. Then I saw [this code](https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/qemu+v2.0.0/util/crc32c.c#L108) and decided that was easier for me to understand, this is what I based my current code on.

Here is my current code:

```
static unsigned long crc_table[256] = {
  0x00000000, 0xf26b8303, 0xe13b70f7, 0x1350f3f4, 0xc79a971f, 0x35f1141c, 0x26a1e7e8, 0xd4ca64eb,
  0x8ad958cf, 0x78b2dbcc, 0x6be22838, 0x9989ab3b, 0x4d43cfd0, 0xbf284cd3, 0xac78bf27, 0x5e133c24,
  0x105ec76f, 0xe235446c, 0xf165b798, 0x030e349b, 0xd7c45070, 0x25afd373, 0x36ff2087, 0xc494a384,
  0x9a879fa0, 0x68ec1ca3, 0x7bbcef57, 0x89d76c54, 0x5d1d08bf, 0xaf768bbc, 0xbc267848, 0x4e4dfb4b,
  0x20bd8ede, 0xd2d60ddd, 0xc186fe29, 0x33ed7d2a, 0xe72719c1, 0x154c9ac2, 0x061c6936, 0xf477ea35,
  0xaa64d611, 0x580f5512, 0x4b5fa6e6, 0xb93425e5, 0x6dfe410e, 0x9f95c20d, 0x8cc531f9, 0x7eaeb2fa,
  0x30e349b1, 0xc288cab2, 0xd1d83946, 0x23b3ba45, 0xf779deae, 0x05125dad, 0x1642ae59, 0xe4292d5a,
  0xba3a117e, 0x4851927d, 0x5b016189, 0xa96ae28a, 0x7da08661, 0x8fcb0562, 0x9c9bf696, 0x6ef07595,
  0x417b1dbc, 0xb3109ebf, 0xa0406d4b, 0x522bee48, 0x86e18aa3, 0x748a09a0, 0x67dafa54, 0x95b17957,
  0xcba24573, 0x39c9c670, 0x2a993584, 0xd8f2b687, 0x0c38d26c, 0xfe53516f, 0xed03a29b, 0x1f682198,
  0x5125dad3, 0xa34e59d0, 0xb01eaa24, 0x42752927, 0x96bf4dcc, 0x64d4cecf, 0x77843d3b, 0x85efbe38,
  0xdbfc821c, 0x2997011f, 0x3ac7f2eb, 0xc8ac71e8, 0x1c661503, 0xee0d9600, 0xfd5d65f4, 0x0f36e6f7, 
  0x61c69362, 0x93ad1061, 0x80fde395, 0x72966096, 0xa65c047d, 0x5437877e, 0x4767748a, 0xb50cf789, 
  0xeb1fcbad, 0x197448ae, 0x0a24bb5a, 0xf84f3859, 0x2c855cb2, 0xdeeedfb1, 0xcdbe2c45, 0x3fd5af46, 
  0x7198540d, 0x83f3d70e, 0x90a324fa, 0x62c8a7f9, 0xb602c312, 0x44694011, 0x5739b3e5, 0xa55230e6, 
  0xfb410cc2, 0x092a8fc1, 0x1a7a7c35, 0xe811ff36, 0x3cdb9bdd, 0xceb018de, 0xdde0eb2a, 0x2f8b6829, 
  0x82f63b78, 0x709db87b, 0x63cd4b8f, 0x91a6c88c, 0x456cac67, 0xb7072f64, 0xa457dc90, 0x563c5f93, 
  0x082f63b7, 0xfa44e0b4, 0xe9141340, 0x1b7f9043, 0xcfb5f4a8, 0x3dde77ab, 0x2e8e845f, 0xdce5075c, 
  0x92a8fc17, 0x60c37f14, 0x73938ce0, 0x81f80fe3, 0x55326b08, 0xa759e80b, 0xb4091bff, 0x466298fc, 
  0x1871a4d8, 0xea1a27db, 0xf94ad42f, 0x0b21572c, 0xdfeb33c7, 0x2d80b0c4, 0x3ed04330, 0xccbbc033, 
  0xa24bb5a6, 0x502036a5, 0x4370c551, 0xb11b4652, 0x65d122b9, 0x97baa1ba, 0x84ea524e, 0x7681d14d, 
  0x2892ed69, 0xdaf96e6a, 0xc9a99d9e, 0x3bc21e9d, 0xef087a76, 0x1d63f975, 0x0e330a81, 0xfc588982, 
  0xb21572c9, 0x407ef1ca, 0x532e023e, 0xa145813d, 0x758fe5d6, 0x87e466d5, 0x94b49521, 0x66df1622, 
  0x38cc2a06, 0xcaa7a905, 0xd9f75af1, 0x2b9cd9f2, 0xff56bd19, 0x0d3d3e1a, 0x1e6dcdee, 0xec064eed, 
  0xc38d26c4, 0x31e6a5c7, 0x22b65633, 0xd0ddd530, 0x0417b1db, 0xf67c32d8, 0xe52cc12c, 0x1747422f, 
  0x49547e0b, 0xbb3ffd08, 0xa86f0efc, 0x5a048dff, 0x8ecee914, 0x7ca56a17, 0x6ff599e3, 0x9d9e1ae0,
  0xd3d3e1ab, 0x21b862a8, 0x32e8915c, 0xc083125f, 0x144976b4, 0xe622f5b7, 0xf5720643, 0x07198540, 
  0x590ab964, 0xab613a67, 0xb831c993, 0x4a5a4a90, 0x9e902e7b, 0x6cfbad78, 0x7fab5e8c, 0x8dc0dd8f, 
  0xe330a81a, 0x115b2b19, 0x020bd8ed, 0xf0605bee, 0x24aa3f05, 0xd6c1bc06, 0xc5914ff2, 0x37faccf1, 
  0x69e9f0d5, 0x9b8273d6, 0x88d28022, 0x7ab90321, 0xae7367ca, 0x5c18e4c9, 0x4f48173d, 0xbd23943e, 
  0xf36e6f75, 0x0105ec76, 0x12551f82, 0xe03e9c81, 0x34f4f86a, 0xc69f7b69, 0xd5cf889d, 0x27a40b9e, 
  0x79b737ba, 0x8bdcb4b9, 0x988c474d, 0x6ae7c44e, 0xbe2da0a5, 0x4c4623a6, 0x5f16d052, 0xad7d5351 
};

unsigned long crc_string(char *s)
{
  unsigned long crc = 0xffffffff; 
  while (*s){
    crc = crc_table[(crc ^ ((uint8_t) hex2int(*s++))) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
  }
  crc = ~crc;
  
  return crc;
}

int hex2int(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}
```

An example of a packet I'm working with is:

```
B100880000000000C840C000160C0E0E2400CD19921979194B00004B00004A00004B00004B00004A00004A00004B00004B00004B00004A00004A00004B00004A00004A00004B00004A00004B00004A00004B00004B00004B00004A00004A00004A00004B00004A00004B00004A00004A00004B00004B00004A00004B00004B00004A00004B00004B0D66BC1B0D0A
```

Where the checksum is: `0D66BC1B`

And the checksum from my function is: `348BA995`

The data entering crc_string is:

```
00000000C840C000160C0E0E2400CD19921979194B00004B00004A00004B00004B00004A00004A00004B00004B00004B00004A00004A00004B00004A00004A00004B00004A00004B00004A00004B00004B00004B00004A00004A00004A00004B00004A00004B00004A00004A00004B00004B00004A00004B00004B00004A00004B00004B
```

Other information:
The data is initially received at a byte array that is changed to a String of hex for simplicity of reading. Please see the following function for details:

```
void array_to_string(byte array[], unsigned int len, char buffer[]) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {  // make this len*2 ? to avoid buffer overflow
    byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
    byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
    buffer[i * 2 + 0] = nib1 < 0xA ? '0' + nib1 : 'A' + nib1 - 0xA;
    buffer[i * 2 + 1] = nib2 < 0xA ? '0' + nib2 : 'A' + nib2 - 0xA;
  }
  buffer[len * 2] = '\0';
}
```

The following is a larger portion of the file I am working with. An example of currentDataString is equibilent to "example of a packet" that was listed above.

```
void array_to_string(byte array[], unsigned int len, char buffer[]) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {  // make this len*2 ? to avoid buffer overflow
    byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
    byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
    buffer[i * 2 + 0] = nib1 < 0xA ? '0' + nib1 : 'A' + nib1 - 0xA;
    buffer[i * 2 + 1] = nib2 < 0xA ? '0' + nib2 : 'A' + nib2 - 0xA;
  }
  buffer[len * 2] = '\0';
}

static void notifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic *pBLERemoteCharacteristic, byte pData[], size_t length, bool isNotify) {
  array_to_string(pData, length, currentData);
  Serial.print(F("Clean data: "));
  Serial.println(currentData);
  String currentDataString(currentData);
  else if(currentDataString.indexOf("B100")!= -1){ 
    Serial.println("b100 Data");
    if(checkCRC(currentDataString)){
      Serial.println("Good Data");
    }
  }
}

boolean checkCRC(String currentDataString){
  int len = currentDataString.length(); 
  String newCRC = currentDataString.substring(8,len - 12 );
  char buf[len- 8 - 12];
  newCRC.toCharArray(buf, len-8-12);
  unsigned long newFunction = crc_string(buf);
  Serial.println(crc_string(buf), HEX);
  Serial.print(F("newCRC: "));
  Serial.println(newCRC);

  String GivenCRC = currentDataString.substring(len - 4 - 8 ,len - 4 ); 
  Serial.print(F("GivenCRC: "));
  Serial.println(GivenCRC);
  return newCRC == GivenCRC;
}
```

Comment: why `hex2int`? That doens't look right at all.

Comment: @Jason I wasn't sure if the default type for *s was being recognized as base 16 and not base 10 so I changed it to an integer and then added a uint8_t cast just to be redundant. [This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839558/hex-char-to-int-conversion) I found the code for that function from

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Is your input really a hex string representation of the data? Even if you are transferring hex data, I would expect real line termination characters at the end instead of a hex string `0D0A`. How exactly do you display the packets to get these hex strings? Your CRC table seems to be designed for 8-bit input values while your function `hex2int` converts a single character which represents 4 bits. (The table in the linked Arduino example is for 4-bit input and `crc_update` splits the 8-bit input into two 4-bit values.)

Comment: Once, your code is compiled, there is no more base 16 vs base 10.  It's all binary.  `0xf == 15`.  Once compiled, these 2 values are identical

Comment: Bodo has a point as well.  Are you sending raw bytes, or are you sending quoted strings of hex?  Meaning, are you sending 0xAA, or "0xAA"?

Comment: @Bobo I just added more information, does that cover all the questions you had? I can keep adding info.

Comment: If you really want to use a hex string as input, you could change the function `hex2int` to convert 2 hex-digits to an 8-bit value and then the loop should increment the pointer by 2. Note that the error handling might be difficult in case the input string consists of an odd number of hex-digits or contains invalid characters. Do you really *need* to convert the byte array to a hex string before CRC calculation? I would suggest to calculate the CRC first, then convert to a string, *if necessary*, e.g. because you want to transfer it as text. A debugger can display binary data as a hexdump.

Comment: @Jason I believe I'm using quoted strings of hex but instead of "0xAA" its just "AA"

Comment: BTW: `currentDataString.length()` seems to be C++, not C. Here `currentDataString` seems to be a C++ string. Your function `array_to_string` fills a `char` array which can be used as a C string. I suggest to create a [mre] by adding a main program (probably `setup` and `loop` functions) that shows how all functions are supposed to work together.

Comment: Wait... You get raw data and convert it into a string to crc??  Just crc the raw data.  You can keep the string if you need it, but crcing the string is an unnecessary level of complication.

Comment: **Please don't replace the code in your question** with code from an answer or make fundamental changes after answers have been written because the answers will then no longer match your question. Adding the `setup` and `loop` functions (or a `main` function for other platforms) is OK but keep your original code. Then we might be able to test our proposed solutions. Please use *your* `crc_string` and `hex2int` functions and show the resulting output.

Comment: Please also add details where data in the hex string or byte array comes from and a specification of the CRC algorithm that was used to calculate the CRC that is part of the data.

Comment: @Bodo I added details in the last code snipped about where my data comes from. Would you like to see more about my Bluetooth calls? The specification I was directed to was [this crc32c calc](https://crccalc.com/) Does that clear anything up?

Comment: With "where the data comes from" I meant what device or software produces the CRC and how is the CRC specified? To me it is still not clear if we have an error in the implementation of the CRC calculation or maybe a wrong CRC algorithm. Did you verify that the CRC algorithm uses the correct polynomial? BTW: The Arduino example refers to [pycrc](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/) which is a code generator for CRC algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending raw bytes, this should work just fine:

Edit: sorry, the original solution only focused on the contents of generating the crc.  I added a `len` parameter as well.

```
unsigned long crc_string(char *s, int len)
{
  unsigned long crc = 0xffffffff; 
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < len; ++i){
    crc = crc_table[((crc << 8) ^ *s++) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
  }
  crc = ~crc;
  
  return crc;
}
```

Another way to do this, would be to send a `seed` parameter so you can crc on the fly better.

```
unsigned long crc_string(char *s, int len, unsigned long seed)
```

Then, you begin by setting `crc` to `seed` instead of `0xffffffff`.

What you have would work if you had something like this:

```
const char* s = "ab0c135a";
crc_string(s);
```

I'd be really surprised if you are actually getting hex *strings*.

Comment: The loop would use all data up to the first byte of value 0. Raw bytes can usually contain value 0. The question needs clarification before it can be answered.

Comment: @Bodo WHOOPS, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to calculate the CRC *before* converting the byte array to a hex string. Add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question  to get a detailed solution.

If the hex string representation is only for debugging/printing, then there might be alternatives that don't need the conversion of the whole byte array.

---

Your CRC table is designed for 8-bit input values while your function `hex2int` converts a single character which represents 4 bits only.

This means that you feed wrong data into your CRC calculation.

This can be fixed by converting two characters of the hex-string input to a byte that is fed into the CRC calculation.

```
int hex2nibble(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}

int hex2byte(const char *p)
{
    int byte = hex2nibble(*p++);
    /* If the 1st character was invalid we want to keep the -1. */
    if(byte >= 0)
    {
        /* Cast to unsigned because bit operations on signed data might be implementation defined. */
        unsigned int val = (unsigned int)byte;
        val <<= 4;
        val |= (unsigned int)hex2nibble(*p);
        byte = (int)val;
    }
    return byte;
}

/* I suggest to replace unsigned int with uint32_t for portable code.*/
unsigned int crc_string(const char *s)
{
    unsigned int crc = 0xffffffff; 
    while (*s){
        /* note: missing error handling for return value -1 */
        crc = crc_table[(crc ^ ((uint8_t) hex2byte(s))) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
        s += 2;
    }
    crc = ~crc;
  
    return crc;
}
```

I'm not able to test the proposed code on an Arduino.

---

Tested standard C++ version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

static uint32_t crc_table[256] = {
  0x00000000, 0xf26b8303, 0xe13b70f7, 0x1350f3f4, 0xc79a971f, 0x35f1141c, 0x26a1e7e8, 0xd4ca64eb,
  0x8ad958cf, 0x78b2dbcc, 0x6be22838, 0x9989ab3b, 0x4d43cfd0, 0xbf284cd3, 0xac78bf27, 0x5e133c24,
  0x105ec76f, 0xe235446c, 0xf165b798, 0x030e349b, 0xd7c45070, 0x25afd373, 0x36ff2087, 0xc494a384,
  0x9a879fa0, 0x68ec1ca3, 0x7bbcef57, 0x89d76c54, 0x5d1d08bf, 0xaf768bbc, 0xbc267848, 0x4e4dfb4b,
  0x20bd8ede, 0xd2d60ddd, 0xc186fe29, 0x33ed7d2a, 0xe72719c1, 0x154c9ac2, 0x061c6936, 0xf477ea35,
  0xaa64d611, 0x580f5512, 0x4b5fa6e6, 0xb93425e5, 0x6dfe410e, 0x9f95c20d, 0x8cc531f9, 0x7eaeb2fa,
  0x30e349b1, 0xc288cab2, 0xd1d83946, 0x23b3ba45, 0xf779deae, 0x05125dad, 0x1642ae59, 0xe4292d5a,
  0xba3a117e, 0x4851927d, 0x5b016189, 0xa96ae28a, 0x7da08661, 0x8fcb0562, 0x9c9bf696, 0x6ef07595,
  0x417b1dbc, 0xb3109ebf, 0xa0406d4b, 0x522bee48, 0x86e18aa3, 0x748a09a0, 0x67dafa54, 0x95b17957,
  0xcba24573, 0x39c9c670, 0x2a993584, 0xd8f2b687, 0x0c38d26c, 0xfe53516f, 0xed03a29b, 0x1f682198,
  0x5125dad3, 0xa34e59d0, 0xb01eaa24, 0x42752927, 0x96bf4dcc, 0x64d4cecf, 0x77843d3b, 0x85efbe38,
  0xdbfc821c, 0x2997011f, 0x3ac7f2eb, 0xc8ac71e8, 0x1c661503, 0xee0d9600, 0xfd5d65f4, 0x0f36e6f7, 
  0x61c69362, 0x93ad1061, 0x80fde395, 0x72966096, 0xa65c047d, 0x5437877e, 0x4767748a, 0xb50cf789, 
  0xeb1fcbad, 0x197448ae, 0x0a24bb5a, 0xf84f3859, 0x2c855cb2, 0xdeeedfb1, 0xcdbe2c45, 0x3fd5af46, 
  0x7198540d, 0x83f3d70e, 0x90a324fa, 0x62c8a7f9, 0xb602c312, 0x44694011, 0x5739b3e5, 0xa55230e6, 
  0xfb410cc2, 0x092a8fc1, 0x1a7a7c35, 0xe811ff36, 0x3cdb9bdd, 0xceb018de, 0xdde0eb2a, 0x2f8b6829, 
  0x82f63b78, 0x709db87b, 0x63cd4b8f, 0x91a6c88c, 0x456cac67, 0xb7072f64, 0xa457dc90, 0x563c5f93, 
  0x082f63b7, 0xfa44e0b4, 0xe9141340, 0x1b7f9043, 0xcfb5f4a8, 0x3dde77ab, 0x2e8e845f, 0xdce5075c, 
  0x92a8fc17, 0x60c37f14, 0x73938ce0, 0x81f80fe3, 0x55326b08, 0xa759e80b, 0xb4091bff, 0x466298fc, 
  0x1871a4d8, 0xea1a27db, 0xf94ad42f, 0x0b21572c, 0xdfeb33c7, 0x2d80b0c4, 0x3ed04330, 0xccbbc033, 
  0xa24bb5a6, 0x502036a5, 0x4370c551, 0xb11b4652, 0x65d122b9, 0x97baa1ba, 0x84ea524e, 0x7681d14d, 
  0x2892ed69, 0xdaf96e6a, 0xc9a99d9e, 0x3bc21e9d, 0xef087a76, 0x1d63f975, 0x0e330a81, 0xfc588982, 
  0xb21572c9, 0x407ef1ca, 0x532e023e, 0xa145813d, 0x758fe5d6, 0x87e466d5, 0x94b49521, 0x66df1622, 
  0x38cc2a06, 0xcaa7a905, 0xd9f75af1, 0x2b9cd9f2, 0xff56bd19, 0x0d3d3e1a, 0x1e6dcdee, 0xec064eed, 
  0xc38d26c4, 0x31e6a5c7, 0x22b65633, 0xd0ddd530, 0x0417b1db, 0xf67c32d8, 0xe52cc12c, 0x1747422f, 
  0x49547e0b, 0xbb3ffd08, 0xa86f0efc, 0x5a048dff, 0x8ecee914, 0x7ca56a17, 0x6ff599e3, 0x9d9e1ae0,
  0xd3d3e1ab, 0x21b862a8, 0x32e8915c, 0xc083125f, 0x144976b4, 0xe622f5b7, 0xf5720643, 0x07198540, 
  0x590ab964, 0xab613a67, 0xb831c993, 0x4a5a4a90, 0x9e902e7b, 0x6cfbad78, 0x7fab5e8c, 0x8dc0dd8f, 
  0xe330a81a, 0x115b2b19, 0x020bd8ed, 0xf0605bee, 0x24aa3f05, 0xd6c1bc06, 0xc5914ff2, 0x37faccf1, 
  0x69e9f0d5, 0x9b8273d6, 0x88d28022, 0x7ab90321, 0xae7367ca, 0x5c18e4c9, 0x4f48173d, 0xbd23943e, 
  0xf36e6f75, 0x0105ec76, 0x12551f82, 0xe03e9c81, 0x34f4f86a, 0xc69f7b69, 0xd5cf889d, 0x27a40b9e, 
  0x79b737ba, 0x8bdcb4b9, 0x988c474d, 0x6ae7c44e, 0xbe2da0a5, 0x4c4623a6, 0x5f16d052, 0xad7d5351 
};

int hex2nibble(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}

int hex2byte(const char *p)
{
    int byte = hex2nibble(*p++);
    /* If the 1st character was invalid we want to keep the -1. */
    if(byte >= 0)
    {
        /* Cast to unsigned because bit operations on signed data might be implementation defined. */
        unsigned int val = (unsigned int)byte;
        val <<= 4;
        val |= (unsigned int)hex2nibble(*p);
        byte = (int)val;
    }
    return byte;
}

/* Replaced unsigned int with uint32_t for portable code. */
uint32_t crc_string(const char *s)
{
    uint32_t crc = 0xffffffff; 
    while (*s){
        /* note: missing error handling for return value -1 */
        crc = crc_table[(crc ^ ((uint8_t) hex2byte(s))) & 0xff] ^ (crc >> 8);
        s += 2;
    }
    crc = ~crc;
  
    return crc;
}

int main()
{
    string currentDataString = "B100880000000000C840C000160C0E101E00B219761954194C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004CDC49F5C30D0A";

    cout << "input:      " << currentDataString << endl;
  
    int len = currentDataString.length();
    string newCRC = currentDataString.substr(8, len - 12 -8 );
  
    const char *buf = newCRC.c_str();
  
    cout << "newCRCFrom: " << "        " << newCRC << endl;
    cout << "newCRC:     " << hex << crc_string(buf) << endl;
  
    string GivenCRC = currentDataString.substr(len - 4 - 8, 8); // TODO we only need to put the CRC to a string not the whole packet
    cout << "GivenCRC:   " << GivenCRC << endl;

    cout << "Valid:      " << (newCRC == GivenCRC) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
input:      B100880000000000C840C000160C0E101E00B219761954194C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004CDC49F5C30D0A
newCRCFrom:         00000000C840C000160C0E101E00B219761954194C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004C00004D00004C00004C
newCRC:     c3f549dc
GivenCRC:   DC49F5C3
Valid:      0
```

As you can see, the calculated CRC is basically the same, but the data string contains the CRC as bytes in little-endian byte order while the string of the calculated CRC shows the hex representation of a 4-byte number in the normal byte order.

The information that the CRC is stored in little-endian byte order is missing in the question. (This should be part of the specification that I requested in a comment.)

---

The table in the linked [Arduino example](https://excamera.com/sphinx/article-crc.html) is for 4-bit input and `crc_update` splits the 8-bit input into two 4-bit values. This table could be used if you want to feed 4-bit values into the CRC calculation. The Arduino solution feeds the lower nibble first into the CRC calculation. The untested proposal below will feed the higher nibble first, so this calculation might be wrong.

```
static PROGMEM prog_uint32_t crc_table[16] = {
    0x00000000, 0x1db71064, 0x3b6e20c8, 0x26d930ac,
    0x76dc4190, 0x6b6b51f4, 0x4db26158, 0x5005713c,
    0xedb88320, 0xf00f9344, 0xd6d6a3e8, 0xcb61b38c,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0x86d3d2d4, 0xa00ae278, 0xbdbdf21c
};

unsigned long crc_string(char *s)
{
    unsigned long crc = 0xffffffff; 
    while (*s){
        crc = pgm_read_dword_near(crc_table + ((uint8_t) hex2int(*s++) & 0x0f))
            ^ (crc >> 4);
    }
    crc = ~crc;
  
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code snippet to be runnable with the functions you're using. I had no luck with the second suggestion you gave yesterday when I attempted it but can do back and try again today if you still think it'll work better than what I currently have.

Comment: I just noticed that the untested code based on the 4-bit CRC table feeds the two nibbles (half-bytes) in a different order than the Arduino example code. I meant to show in your question an example including `array_to_string` because calculating the CRC from the byte array would be the best and easiest solution.

Comment: @EmmaatFarrPro My code contained an error that should be reported by the compiler. I called `hex2byte` wrongly with the character value instead of the pointer. I added a tested standard C++ version of the code that shows a byte order problem when comparing the CRC strings.